# Prove $a$ approaches $0$, if $a<|b|$ and $b$ approaches $0$?

Tags: limits, inequality

Prove $a$ approaches $0$, if $a<|b|$ and $b$ approaches $0$?

It looks silly, but I can't write something down to prove it.

Comment: $b$ approaches $0$ means $|b|$ is less than any arbitrary $ε > 0$, and so is $a$.

Comment: $a\lt |b|\implies -b\lt a\lt b$

Comment: I find here is a question about some number approaches 0, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665752/what-does-approach-zero-really-mean      I'm starting learning calculus, Anik's answer is convincing to me , thank you all!

Comment: The simplest proof: $-b\le a\le b$ and [sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: This is not true. For example, $a_n=-1, b_n=1/n$ then we have $a_n=-1<1/n=|b_n|$ and $b_n\to 0$ but $a$ certainly does not approach zero. Indeed any sequence $a_n$ which has a negative limit and stays below $|b_n|$ suffices. If you insist $a_n$ have a non-negative limit (or even stronger, is always non-negative) then you get the result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $a < \lvert b \rvert $. Assume that b approaches zero. This means that for any fixed $\epsilon$  we can make $b$ closer to zero than $\epsilon$ , which is the same thing as saying $\lvert b-0 \rvert\le\lvert\epsilon-0\rvert$, or just $\lvert b \rvert\le\lvert\epsilon\rvert$ .  Thus if  $a < \lvert b \rvert $, then by the transitive property $a\lt\epsilon$. Since this is any arbitary epsilon, $a$ must also approach zero

Comment: But that doesn't mean $|a|<\epsilon$ which would be what we want.